# iOS - Tabbar with navigation controller and back button issue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an issue I don't know how to resolve. My Storyboard looks like this:

```
NavigationController -> ViewController (Start) -> TabBarController
```

Then I have 5 `ViewController` connected to the `TabBarController` and each of them is embedded in a `NavigationController`.

My issue is when I click in of these embedded `ViewControllers` to push a view and then click the `Back` button, it takes me to the root `ViewController (Start)` but instead I want to go back one step inside the `TabBarController`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: have you tried putting Navigationbar before tabbarcontoller ?

Comment: You can try in the following order TabBarController-> NavigationController -> ViewController (Start)

Comment: I need to have this order. Because "Start" is the first view without any menu, then when you click on a button it takes you to the tab bar with menus,

Comment: You should use Navigation controller as child of tabbar for better controll

Comment: You can hide tabbar for your first view and then show tabbar when it push

Comment: But then my start need to be a child for tabbar? so instead of 5 i will have 6 bar items?

Comment: Y don't you present your Start in tabbar controller even it doesn't want any menu?

Comment: I still dont get it, i but now Start in tab bar. So I have 4 items and "More" item at the most right.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/infinitabbar you can use infinite tabBar. This may be not the exact solution but can work in this situation.

Comment: one more solution I can suggest is at the start set your window.rootviewController to startViewController at the start and when you tap any button on startViewController, you can change the window.rootViewController property to show the TaBBarViewController. You can change the back and forth by changing window.rootviewController. Again it's just a work around but effective.

Answer (score 0):

I believe TabBarController must always be the top-level Controller in your app. From there you can cascade to individual ViewControllers and they can be embedded in NavigationControllers or not. But TabBarController must be your the starting point in the hierarchy.

You can still have your Start VC somewhere under the TabBarController and can either hide tabbar or you can present the Start VC modally (still in viewdidload in full screen without any menus) and then unwind from there back wherever you need.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But my Start view need to start the tab bar, and from tab bar I need to be able to go back to start. If I put Start under tab bar, i will have 6 menus instead of 5.

Comment: Why don't you put Start modally under one of those 5 VC you have under TBC?

Answer (score 0):

Your TabBarController Should be the rootViewController of NavigationController,

So the flow of your Storyboard must be like,

```
    NavigationController -> TabBarController -> ViewControllers
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your heirarchy is as below

```
NavigationController -> ViewController (Start) -> TabBarController -> NavigationController1
                                                                   -> NavigationController2
                                                                   -> NavigationController3 
                                                                   -> NavigationController4           
                                                                   -> NavigationController5
```

In each child ViewController you can write

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this solves your problem.